# What is the use of Google’s "Google Search" Button?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

I'm sure whenever we used to type a keyword in the search bar of Google, the Google changes its search bar UI and the search button become useless in the home page.

[image: Google homepage UI]

[image: Google Instant UI]

[image]

Comment: Does it also work this was when Javascript is turned off? Might also work different on mobile versions of the page. I guess the additional Search button is just a failsafe for these cases.

Comment: Let our powers combine. Affordance, Usability, Compatibility, Familiarity, and maybe a hint of Nostalgia. By these powers combined, we have a webpage where you know precisely how to interact!

Comment: In the earliest days of the web, forms required at least one actual submit button to be present in the form. Those are those buttons.

Comment: Apart from technical fallback and per-user options listed in answers below, I also see it as brand/product marketing. Had the button said "Search" it would not have been, but now it's "Google Search" -- the name of [Google's search engine product/service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search).

Comment: Great question! The "Google Search" button is even a "useless button" when the search box is empty. I've also investigated that the "I'm feeling lucky!" button redirects you to the doodle-archives and also disappears when something is typed into the text-box. Check out this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30486/why-is-googles-im-feeling-lucky-button-still-next-to-the-search-bar

Comment: Also: The user can configure google search not to do auto fill in(Personally I hate that feature, so I always disable it).

Comment: The buttons are not on my iPad unless I request the desktop site.

Comment: @Superbest sarcasm, right?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Nope

Comment: @Pradeep, why do you have 8 revisions over the last month and a half that are nothing more than modifying whitespace? This question is answered. Please stop bumping it to the top.

Comment: One of my google fren just replied with 2 reasons. First, having button doesn't create any problem and Second, removing button doesn't solve any problem.

Comment: 1. Touch devices.    2.The search bar looks too *naked* without it.

Comment: It seems Google has now updated their interface so that the Search Google button is now a part of the quick search drop down menu after you start typing. At least for desktop devices. Probably for mobile devices there may still be the square button magnifying glass icon because that seems to be a standard metaphor on mobile devices.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Wonderful observation :)
Tried it without Javascript as @J_rgen suggested. Might as well be for the same reason. A fallback for other browsers etc.

Also if you consider from a experience aspect, not having a button would seem somewhat incomplete. Not a perfect reason, but might as well be.

Also, I directly asked an ex designer of google.om itself the reason. Here is what he had to say. [image]

[image]

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that google detects a slow connection and will degrade to not automatically searching, I've had this happen to me a few times.

Comment: I think your second paragraph is not correct. The problem is not that "not having a button would seem somewhat incomplete." the problem is that Instant Search is not always performed (for a variety of reasons) and it would be **inconsistent** to have the page suddenly change adding or removing some UI controls just because this hidden feature becomes active/not-active. Consistency is a *big* concern in UX, and since keeping the button has no downsides there is no reason to *not* place the button in all cases.

Comment: This is kind of like the save button in Gmail. There was a time when the save button literally did nothing at all because Gmail auto-saved as you typed. But when the Gmail team got rid of the save button people freaked out because they "couldn't save"

Comment: @DavidGrinberg That's hilarious, except why would the save buttons functionality be _removed_? How could it do _nothing_?

Comment: @Insane they probably started with manual save, then added autosave (probably with a slow roll-out, possibly not guaranteed to match the UI update rollout)

Comment: @Bakuriu no downsides? Google serves 3.5 billion searches a day - if that button is 50 bytes, and 50% of users don't need it, that's 17.5 GB of bandwidth they've saved...

Comment: @Tim Which is zero if you consider the bandwidth they have available. Also: if a webpage changes at random times caching becomes infeasible/not efficient. By always providing the same page you allow the browser to use better caching, which means *better* bandwidth usage.

Comment: @Insane because it's function was automated. By the time you pressed save your email would already be saved, so there was never a case where the save button could do anything

Comment: In my opinion the first argument is invalid, because they could remove the button with javascript.

Comment: Please consider making your answer permanently useful by including what @J_rgen actually said (in a comment t the q). Comments are not intended to be kept around forever and your post needs his comment to make sense.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment

Comment: so basically the Google person said what I said in this very same page based on Google's documentation and nobody paid attention to. Well...      ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, But I am still amazed at how the designers at google have given some lame reasons like "Balancing the I am Feeling Lucky button". If you'd ask me, the search button could be beside the input field(consistent to the next screen) and the IFL button could be center aligned to maintain balance. Also serves the 1st point

Comment: @SaurabhKumarSuman he gave three reasons, of which that was the third and presumably least significant.

Comment: @Insane remember how long Gmail has been about. It's likely they had it there as a way to provide comfort to users skeptical of the auto-save feature (which was incredibly rare in web applications at the time).

Answer (score 119):

There are three reasons:

1. You have JavaScript disabled on your browser.
2. Your internet is slow and/or has high latency to Google's servers. (Try this – Google on a slower or high latency connection! It disables instant search)
3. You use a browser that doesn't support instant.

[Bonus] It has been there always and removing it would confuse people in addition to breaking search on above scenarios.

Comment: I would even say that Point 1 should say something similar to "You have Javascript disabled or your browser doesn't support it at all (WAP browsers, text-only browsers like Linx, old Internet Explorer)".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel that would work but you then have to do extra work. Also that would confuse people at first.  Google wants everyone to use their service so thew want an page that works everywhere and is as light as possible. In current situation, the are able to do that while dynamically hiding the button would just make the page larger

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Having both option (to hit search button/enter and Google instant) adds redundancy. Suddenly removing the search button would confuse people even though they don't use it. So its better keeping it as is. Plus as you mentioned you can dynamically remove it if instant is being used but that would a. Add complexity to he page and b. Make the page larger. Having a complex site has greater chances of breaking on an obscure or older browser and having an heavier website is bad for slower/unstable connection

Comment: Actually, what I was saying was to actualy expand a bit on the first point.

Comment: I'd also add that people can explicitly *disable* instant search, even without disabling Javascript. In that case the page will *have* to wait for an Enter/click on the button.

Comment: 4. Your search terms include something that will give you porn, so instant is temporarily switched off.

Comment: 3a. You turned off instant search.

Comment: 5.  Your search is too long: I've seen some complex searches result in "press enter to search" appearing as well as intstant not doing anything

Comment: 6. The services that enable instant search at Google are overloaded or failed

Comment: @TylerH I meant Google search on a poor quality connection. I have edited the answer to reflect that and be more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: But here my question is why the "Google Search" button disappears and changes its UI. It may have good experience with old users, let's think about a fresh user to Google.

Comment: @Pradeep Let me ask this: how exactly would you differentiate old user versus new?

Comment: @Roh_mish I'll explain you clearly, If I am new to Google's home page where I used to see a "Google Search" button prominently before typing a keyword, after typing a keyword the "Google Search" button disappears and changes into search Icon.

Comment: @Pradeep  magnifying glass icon as the search icon is accepted as the normal iconography everywhere. Maybe thats why

Comment: @Roh_mish search icon is accepted, but why there is inconsistency in buttons "Google Search" button in one view and "Icon" in another view.

Comment: @Pradeep I really can't answer that one but I think it's due to the fact that "Google search" as text occupies more space on the page and doesn't stand out much from the otherwise primarily text page as to not imbalance things. Thats not true however on the results page where a small search button is much better suited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45567/discussion-between-pradeep-and-roh-mish).

Comment: @ChrisH I've also found that if you make more than one or two changes to what's in the search box other than the default of "typing more characters at the end" that instant almost always quits running after a moment or two. e.g., clicking in the middle of your text to insert a word, or highlighting a word in the middle and pressing the delete key, etc. Instant gives up pretty quickly in those instances, even on a fast connection and machine.

Comment: Now Google search working as expected. Did Google change something?

Answer (score 35):

**Because users will get confused**

If the search button is removed users will think something is wrong with Google and this will lead to a lot of confusion and abandonment of the search process. This complies with the [consistency heuristic](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/).

**For those who have disabled instant search**

Pradeep is asking the question for the case when the instant search is enabled. However, not every user uses this features so the buttons are left for those who haven't enabled instant search.

**Novice users (elderly people)** who have no computer experience whatsoever might find it useful.

They might not know that pressing the Enter button will show them the results, so the "Google Search" button stays there as it helps this segment of users.

You will be [surprised to see](http://www.internetworldstats.com/stats.htm) what percentage in the world population haven't sit on a computer and don't know how to use the keyboard.

Comment: The thing is, as soon as you start typing the button disappears, and google starts showing results, so you can't even click it.

Comment: @MJB After the user starts typing the buttons are moved to the bottom of the suggested search queries. Also, if you click on a white space the drop down list with the suggested search disappears and buttons are in their original place.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov You must not have instant search in for some reason, with instant search enabled you would be seeing what OP is talking about,

Comment: @JamesTrotter this is the answer. The Search button is placed In case you don't use instant search. If its removed the users will think that there is something wrong with Google and might get confused, that's why they didn't removed it.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov No, when you start typing with instant search on the buttons _are_ removed. He is not asking why the buttons _aren't_ removed, he's asking why the button is there when _it is automatically removed before you can click it_. Your answer does not explain that.

Comment: @JamesTrotter Ok I made a correction to my answer, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @JamesTrotter The button is removed at the same time it starts showing the results, so the user can't possibly get confused about "how can I get my results?". I believe if it decides to stop using Instant then it also displays "Press Enter to search." (for some reason)

Comment: I assume a majority of people don't sit on computers.

Comment: @miva2 then you might be surprised to see how many do...

Answer (score 30):

Firstly, Google Instant is a hidden feature and they provide no cues for it before you begin typing. They can remove the button after the user has begun to type because at this point instant search is *exposed* to the user. Having no search button available before exposing a hidden feature would be potentially confusing to the user.

Secondly, Google Instant is an optional feature and can be switched off in your [search settings](https://www.google.com/preferences). If you have the feature switched off you would need the search button.

[image: Screenshot of Google Instant search settings]

Thirdly, as others have already pointed out Google Instant [isn't always available](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/186645). The button needs to be available in case Google Instant is on but doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot of Google Instant support article]

Comment: I turned off instant results but I am still seeing suggestions.

Comment: @KorayTugay switching off the settings worked for me. Did you scroll to the bottom of the page and click save?

Comment: I have both experiences on a regular basis.  In my main browser window, I am logged in to Google, so it respects my chosen settings (no instant results), and the button is useful.  In my incognito windows, I am not logged in, so the button is superfluous.

Comment: @KorayTugay suggestions or actual search results? Because both are unrelated - _suggestions_ are just that - it's trying to auto-complete but leaving the choice to the user so if you type in `bob` it might suggest `bob's burgers` but it would not act on that suggestion. The _instant search results_ are also exactly what their name implies - you start typing and you get results at the same time. So, if you type in `bob` you will immediately get pages that mention that. You can have both features on or just one and they will still operate in the same way.

Answer (score 14):

This [was tested by Google](http://allthingsd.com/20091030/goog-page/), as you may imagine.

The thing is that they wanted something that works from an UX point of view while keeping the *good ole style* we're used to. Basically, you have 2 main sets:

**Set 1: Have [Google Instant](http://gizmodo.com/5632969/what-is-google-instant) activated**

**Set 2: Have Google Instant disabled**

No matter which set you belong to, you need to see the same page. The user behavior and preferences will create the flow, as in

```
if $instant--> do something else --> do something else
```

you could argue

> "ok, I have my settings in place and I chose **"Google Instant
>   Enabled"**, so why is it still showing the buttons?"

and **the keyword here is consistency**. The addition of those buttons won't add anything to your experience, and it won't cause any harm since they will disappear. But the page is consistent for everybody, so the buttons stand.

Furthermore, the **"I'm feeling lucky"** button which is part of Google brand still exists and it works, so taking off the other button will leave you with just... **I'm feeling lucky**, which is a (supposedly) random search. And **[a very costly feature](http://gawker.com/324927/im-feeling-lucky-button-costs-google-110-million-per-year)**, as we're at it!. Hence, you leave the button and everything works out great for everybody

Comment: Doesn't "I'm Feeling Lucky" take you to the top result?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard yes, it navigates directly there. The article linked explains that by doing that, Google doesn't get to serve you any ads, hence it "costs" them money. Although whether that's correct terminology could be argued - since it's not money actively taken out of their hands, it might be the incorrect thing to call it. Google "doen't get to make those money" might be a better way to call it but I think you'd agree, it doesn't make for a very click bai-...ahem, I mean, _attention grabbing_ title.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard, furhermore, many people thinks it's random because of theuseofthe world *luck* (hence my aggegate of *supposedly* word). Also, if you click that button without any input, it takes you to a page, and different locale have different first results

Answer (score 9):

**Affordance**

Don Norman and James Gibson have differing views on the details of what 'affordance' means but, loosely put, it's allowing the user to perform an action in a way that is obvious to them or making the way to perform that action obvious.

Norman says:

> "...the term affordance refers to the perceived and actual properties of the thing, primarily those fundamental properties that determine just how the thing could possibly be used. [...] Affordances provide strong clues to the operations of things. Plates are for pushing. Knobs are for turning. Slots are for inserting things into. Balls are for throwing or bouncing. When affordances are taken advantage of, the user knows what to do just by looking: no picture, label, or instruction needed." (Norman 1988, p.9)

and Gibson says:

> "an action possibility available in the environment to an individual, independent of the individual's ability to perceive this possibility" (McGrenere and Ho, 2000).

Microsoft products used to use a triplicate model: most primary actions could be performed by either selecting the action from a menu, clicking a button/icon, or activating a keyboard shortcut. This *may* be what Google is doing with their search: Those users familiar with using the button can do so and users familiar with hitting enter can do so - neither set of users will be impeded by the interface.

Comment: Famous Quote: "*I'm so broke, I can't even pay attention.*" (Affordance. Get it?)

Comment: @nocomprende I use a paraphrasing of that quote when talking about my ADD. "I have Attention **Deficit** Disorder. That's why I wasn't paying attention to you; "deficit" means I literally *don't have enough* attention to be able to pay everyone I "owe" attention to. I wish I had an attention surplus..."